# ¿Como hacer que hibernate no comparta el auto-incremento de las id de diferentes tablas?

Tags: hibernate

Me ocurre que tengo un mini programa hecho en java en eclipse y para la parte de la bbdd uso hibernate, pondré aquí el bean autor y el bean libro, y la clase AutorBO. Resulta que cuando hago el alta de un autor con sus 3 libros, si al autor le pone la id 1 en su tabla, en la tabla de libros las IDs de los libros son 2, 3 y 4. Es decir comparten el auto-incrementado.
porque?  y tengo otra duda, hibernate me crea una tabla auxiliar como si estuviese haciendo una relación many2many y no estoy haciendo una relacion muchos a muhcos.

Main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AutorBO abo = new AutorBO();
    String nombre = "fulanito";
    String titulo = "face";
    String titulo2 = "equilibrio";
    String titulo3 = "premunicion";

    abo.alta(nombre, titulo, titulo2, titulo3);


}
```

Autor

```
@Entity

public class Autor {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)//Para generar números 
  autoincrementados
  int id;
  String nombre;
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //eager = 
  carga 
  ansiosa
  List<Libro> libros = new ArrayList<>();



  public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
  }
  public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
  public List<Libro> getLibros() {
    return libros;
  }
  public void setLibros(List<Libro> libros) {
  this.libros = libros;
  }

}
```

Libro

```
@Entity

public class Libro {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)//Para generar números 
  autoincrementados
  private int id;
  private String titulo;
  @ManyToOne
  Autor autor;



  public Libro(String titulo, Autor autor) {
    super();
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autor = autor;
  }



  public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
  }
  public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
  }
  public Autor getAutor() {
    return autor;
  }
  public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
  }


}
```

AutorBO

```
public class AutorBO {

  public void alta(String nombre, String titulo, String titulo2, String 
  titulo3) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Autor a = new Autor();
    a.setNombre(nombre);
    Libro libro1 = new Libro(titulo, a);
    Libro libro2 = new Libro(titulo2, a);
    Libro libro3 = new Libro(titulo3, a);
    a.getLibros().add(libro1);
    a.getLibros().add(libro2);
    a.getLibros().add(libro3);
    session.save(a);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: usa nombres distintos dentro de tus variables id, usa una idlibro, idautor y si no cambia me dices

Comment: voy a robar y te digo, gracias!!

Comment: nada, no cambia

Comment: pero estan en dos tablas separadas el autor y el libro no?

Comment: si si, estan en dos tablas distintas, la tabla libro y la tabla autor.

Comment: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id") 
    private Int id;
Intentalo asi

Comment: segun yo es por eso por que no los estas "conectando" revisa eso

Comment: si mas o menos tienes razon tengo cambiar esto  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
por esto:
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: entonces ya quedo?

Comment: si ya esta solucionado eso, pero no lo otro, me sigue creando una tercera tabla auxiliar como si estuviese haciendo una relacion mucho a muchos.  me crea la tabla libro, la tabla Autor y la tabla Autor_Libro y no deveria crear esta ultima.